# Geb / Groovy - Page content not recognized when used within other Page Object method

Tags: groovy, automated-tests, geb, pageobjects

When I click a button I have to wait for some dynamic content to be rendered.  When I put the waitFor closure in the test it works correctly.  However, I wanted to put the waitFor in a method inside the Page object so I do not have to always call the waitFor after every click, but when I do that it fails stating it cannot find the property.

This does not work:

```
class LandingPage extends Page {
    static content = {
        resultsBtn(to: ResultsPage) { $("button", id: "showresults") }
    }

    void getResults() {
        resultsBtn.click()
        waitFor { ResultsPage.results.displayed }
    }
}

class ResultsPage extends Page {
    static content = { 
        results { $("div", id: "listresults") }
    }
}

class ShowResults extends GebReportingTest {
    @Test
    public void displayResults() {
        to LandingPage
        getResults()
    }
}
```

The error states something like "No such property: results for class ResultsPage".

Is it possible to put references to content from other Page Objects inside other Page Object methods?

EDIT:  I feel like this is more of a Groovy specific thing rather than Geb.  I'm not sure if it's even possible to access bindings within the content closure.  But it also seems like creating a getVariable() function inside the Page Object doesn't help much either.

Answer (score 0):

First you shouldn't assign closures in content blocks (there's unnecessary `=` in `ResultPage`) but pass them to an implicit method, you should have:

```
static content = { 
    results { $("div", id: "listresults") }
}
```

The other question is why do you want to model this as two pages? As far as I understand clicking the button doesn't cause a page reload but there's an ajax call to retrieve the results. I would simply put both `results` and `resultsBtn` as contents of one page and your problem would be gone.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that a page change is involved in your case. Assuming that you always want to wait for these results to appear you can either:

- put your `waitFor` condition inside of `static at = {}` block for `ResultsPage` - [at checks are executed implicitly whenever you use `to()`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#at_checking) which means that it will wait wherever you go to that page
- put a `waitFor` in a [page change listener](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/browser.html#page_change_listening)
- access current page via the browser property on a page, in `LandingPage`: `waitFor { browser.page.results.displayed }` but this seems like a dirty solution to me - reaching from one page to another...

Comment: Fixed the results closure.  To clarify, there is a page change, thats why I use (to: ResultsPage), however, when I get to the ResultsPage I have to check that the results have been fully rendered.  I assume this is because theres some asynchronous content on the results page that is loaded after the page is technically done loading.